# Django memory leak with large queries

Tags: python, django

First things first;

- Debug = False in my settings file
- I am using iterator to go over rows in queryset
- Python 2.7, Django 1.11.12, Ubuntu 16.04, Database Postgresql, Nginx + Gunicorn

I have an endpoint in my application where I run a large query on the database. When a request arrives, I run a query that returns a large number of rows from a large table, go over the results using iterator and construct a list out of the rows, and return the list. I track the memory usage of my Django processes and here is what happens:

- Initially, each process consumes around 40 MBs of memory
- When I run the query for the first time, memory usage goes up to around 700 Mbs
- Second time I run the query (assuming the request landed in the same process), memory usage goes up to around 1400 MBs. And it goes on like this until the server is out of memory.

There seems to be a memory leak here but I couldn't find what is causing it. This is my my view does simply:

```
results = Model.objects.filter(a=1, b=2).values('a', 'b', 'c').order_by('c')
result_list = []
for row in results.iterator():
    result_list.append(row)

return Response({'body': result_list})
```

Any ideas what could be causing the leak?

Comment: check that you select related objects when using relations

Comment: Is the a `Response`, or `JsonResponse`. Looks to me that the queryset is perhaps "linked" by middleware.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It is the response object of Django Rest Framework, returning a Json Response

Comment: @Ozgur Akcali Why don't you use DRF-Serializer?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge for this specific method, I could not achieve what I want by using a serializer, the fields I returns are dynamic, depending on the request. Could using a serilaizer have any effect on the memory leak issue? By the way, when I tried using Django's JsonResponse instead of DRF response, memory leak issue goes away.